# How to get the sum of column in Table2 where table1 meet condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, conditional-aggregation

In my Orders table I have a column Status that holds two items such as 'Paid' or 'Not paid'. In Order Details table I have Amount column. I have written a query to select the number of customer that have not paid and the sum of amount, but it is summing all amount from the Order Details table. I want to get the sum of amount for only those customers that have not paid.

**Orders**

| OrderID | Customer Name | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Mary Vicker | Credit |
| 1002 | Stephanie Musa | Paid |
| 1003 | Peter Crowner | Credit |

**OrderDetails**

| ID | OrderID | Product | Qty | Price | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | Banana | 2 | 4.00 | 8.00 |
| 2 | 1001 | Orange | 1 | 1.00 | 1.00 |
| 3 | 1001 | Apple | 5 | 3.00 | 15.00 |
| 4 | 1002 | Banana | 2 | 2.00 | 4.00 |
| 5 | 1002 | Pawpaw | 2 | 3.00 | 6.00 |
| 6 | 1003 | Apple | 7 | 3.00 | 21.00 |

```
select Sum(CASE WHEN Orders.Status  = 'Credit'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NoOfCreditor, 
Sum(OrderDetails.Amount) as AmountTotal
from Orders
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
```

From the table above the expected out put should be
NoOfCreditor = 2
AmountTotal = 45.00

I'm getting 55.00 as AmountTotal because it sums all. Kindly assist me to write query to get Amount total for credit only

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(OrderDetails.Amount) ... WHERE Orders.Status <> 'Paid'` maybe?

Comment: If you don't want to include it in your where clause or your on clause, just do another case when for your second sum. But it looks to me like you will have the same criteria for both, so I'd say put in the where clause, and use simple sums for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a better approach would be

but your schema is not normalized and the name belongs into a customer table

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT Orders.[OrderID] ) as NoOfCreditor, 
Sum(OrderDetails.Amount) as AmountTotal
from Orders
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID 
WHERE [Status] = 'Credit'
```

| NoOfCreditor | AmountTotal |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 45.00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/m6AQKoSo)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it as follows :

```
select Sum(CASE WHEN Orders.Status  = 'Credit'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NoOfCreditor, 
Sum(CASE WHEN Orders.Status  = 'Credit'  THEN  OrderDetails.Amount ELSE 0 END) as AmountTotal
from Orders
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
```